# Update clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm Giovanni, and I'm a new programmer on CodeIgniter.

Here I want to ask you about Update clause in CodeIgniter,
my code results is unaffected to database, can you correct my code?

Here's my code on my models : news_model.php

```
function autoupdates($id){
    $this->db->set('viewed', 'viewed + 1', FALSE);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('news');
}
```

And on my controllers : news.php

```
$this->news_model->autoupdates($this->uri->segment(4));
```

And the link in my views : news_view.php

```
<?php echo anchor($data2->kategori.'/detail/'.$data2->id,$data2->title) ?>
```

When I try to fill the value of 'id' with a number, the code works, but when I change it to default by using variable ($id) it return a null value, so I can't update a field.

Can you tell me where' my fault?

Thanks before

Comment: echo your last executed query after update call.

Comment: can you post the uri to the controller news

Comment: @kumar_v : I did but still not working..

Comment: @omrehman : pardon me? Sorry, I didn't know what you mean.thanks

Comment: replace and try $this->db->set('viewed', 'viewed + 1');

Comment: @Mani : Still not work... :(

Comment: @user3321830 can u post the link of that action. for example  when u calling **read_news** function in news controller then your uri must be like **http://localhost/mycode/news/read_news**. like that can u post what is shown in the url field when you calling this controller.

Comment: @user3321830 did u echo that $id in that function and check weather the value is coming or not

Comment: @omrehman : when I echo $id, the result is blank..

Comment: @omrehman : what action please?

Comment: can put the values of $data2->kategori ,$data2->id,$data2->title

Comment: @omrehman : okay, here it is : $data2->kategori = news
$data2->id = 41
$data2->title = "Flappy Birds has been suspended"

and the url result is : http://localhost/misnews/news/detail/41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function call statement

`$this->news_model->autoupdates($this->uri->segment(3));` // change 4 to 3

After looking into your code i  found following chagnes:

1 call your autoupdates function in `news` controllers `details()`;

2 update your model code and add false as third parameter in  `$this->db->set('viewed', 'viewed + 1')` line.

Comment: paste your url which calls this auto updates function, href value of your link

Comment: url in address bar after clicking your link.

Comment: ah so.. okay here it is : http://localhost/misnews/news/detail/41
seems the ID is shown, but the "viewed" field is not updated yet

Comment: `echo $this->uri->segment(3)` in your controller before calling your model_function and see if you are getting 41 or not

Comment: have you loaded url helper in controller before calling segment function? or in autoload config file inside config folder?

Comment: mail me here: ravi@karmasource.net

Comment: Please don't make this a private thing, SO is public and all the infos should be available to everyone. How could this be of help to anyone if the matter is settled privately among you two?

Comment: i will post answer after correcting this. hope it will help others as well

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are getting **empty** `$id`. Try `echo '<pre>'; print_r($id); die();` in your model function and see what id you are receiving.